# Local html file with javascript not showing graphs

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net, file, local

New here, sorry if I missed something...

I'm trying to display a local html file in WebBrowser1 that contains javascript that retrieves data from the internet.
The graphs are not displayed, only the title. It works fine in Edge, IE, Firefox and Chrome on my computer. If I load the website on the internet and log in, the graphs is displayed. But I have to use the file from a local html page because it is customized for my purpose. What have I missed?

```
Imports System.IO
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
 WebBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
 Dim filePath As String
 filePath = Application.StartupPath & "\Winningtemp.html"
 WebBrowser1.Url = New Uri(filePath)
 WebBrowser1.Refresh()
End Sub
```

The HTML-file Winningtemp.html:

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" id="***">
 Script follows here... Can't show the code, sorry...
</script>
</body>
```

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2017.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWBdi.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be caused by a low WebBrowser Emulation version.

```
 Private Sub sub_WebBrowser_lastVersionEmulation(Optional ByVal IsDefaultVersion As Boolean = False)
      'WebBrowser Emulation 
      Try
         Dim VersionCode As Integer
         Dim Version As String = ""
         Dim ieVersion As Object = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer").GetValue("svcUpdateVersion")
         If ieVersion Is Nothing Then
            ieVersion = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer").GetValue("Version")
         End If
         If ieVersion IsNot Nothing Then
            Version = ieVersion.ToString.Substring(0, ieVersion.ToString.IndexOf("."c))
            Select Case Version
               Case "7"
                  VersionCode = 7000
               Case "8"
                  VersionCode = 8888
               Case "9"
                  VersionCode = 9999
               Case "10"
                  VersionCode = 10001
               Case Else
                  If CInt(Version) >= 11 Then
                     VersionCode = 11001
                  Else
                     Throw New Exception("IE Version not supported")
                  End If
            End Select
         Else
            Throw New Exception("Registry error")
         End If

         Dim AppName As String = ""
         ''AppName = My.Application.Info.AssemblyName 
         AppName = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName
         Dim sRoot As String = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\"
         Dim sKEY As String = "Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION"
         If IsDefaultVersion = False Then
            'Check if the right emulation is set 
            'if not, Set Emulation to highest level possible on the user machine 
            Dim CurrentSetting As String = CStr(Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(sKEY).GetValue(AppName & ".exe"))
            If CurrentSetting Is Nothing OrElse CInt(CurrentSetting) <> VersionCode Then

               Microsoft.Win32.Registry.SetValue(sRoot & sKEY, AppName & ".exe", VersionCode)
               Microsoft.Win32.Registry.SetValue(sRoot & sKEY, AppName & ".vshost.exe", VersionCode)
            End If
         Else
            'Default Version 
            Microsoft.Win32.Registry.SetValue(sRoot & sKEY, AppName & ".exe", 10001)
            Microsoft.Win32.Registry.SetValue(sRoot & sKEY, AppName & ".vshost.exe", 10001)   
         End If

      Catch ex As Exception
         'skip 
      End Try

   End Sub
```

Comment: The solution "Private Sub sub_WebBrowser_lastVersionEmulation" solved my problem.